# What is the difference between rdiff and librsync?

Tags: rsync, synchronization, rdiff

In my project, I have to keep some files synchronized between two computers.
Both `rdiff` and `librsync` seem to do the same thing. Can anyone please point me to some differences so I can choose which tool would suit me best?

Links to the docs:
http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/librsync.html

http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/rdiff.html

http://linux.die.net/man/3/librsync

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdiff

There maybe more docs available. These are the ones that I read.

Comment: This is about using computers, not computer *science*. Your question may be ontopic on [unix.SE].

Answer (score 1):

librsync is the complete package which ships `rdiff` command.

To use `rdiff` in your system you need to have librsync package installed.

Comment: it is not true, in Debian rdiff is in a separate package.

Comment: @Dārayavahuštdi No, it is true. While it is a separate package, that package depends upon the librsync package.

Answer (score 1):

The best for your needs will be `rsync`, which will synchronize files from one computer to another (if you want two way sync, use [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)).

You can also use tools that build around librsync, such as [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) or [duplicty](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/).

The answer to your question is that `librsync` is a library implementing rsync algorithm, and is used by `rsync` tool but also by the `rdiff` tool, which is somewhat lower level, i.e. you could implement rsync tool using rdiff.